# How to replace all text after the first dot via PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I would like to replace all text after the first dot using a php file. For words I use this code right now:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(  `description`  ,'Facebook',  '')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully with Facebook, ";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " .  $conn->error;
}

$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,'Twitter',  '')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully with Twitter, ";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " .  $conn->error;
}

$conn->close()
```

...but I want to replace/delete all after the first dot.

For example:

Before:

```
Asia's Got Talent Grand Winner El Gamma Penumbra performs on ASAP stage. Subscribe to ABS-CBN Entertainment channel! - Watch the full episodes of ASAP 20 on TFC.TV and on IWANT.TV for Philippine viewers, click: Visit our official website! Facebook: Twitter: Instagram:
```

After:

```
Asia's Got Talent Grand Winner El Gamma Penumbra performs on ASAP stage.
```

Comment: Can you indicate in your script (as a comment) which "dot" you are referring to?

Comment: Also, what is your expected outcome?

Comment: How I can do that. I'm new in PHP :) I have a video description and all what comes after the first dot should be replaced/deleted. This PHP file runs as cronjob in the background. Thank you

Comment: There are many solution for this. You can use explode() function like this:-- $string = explode('.',$str); echo $string[0]; here $str= text in which you want to remove text after dot.

Comment: How to use this? Also I don't know what comes after the first dot :).

Comment: imo, You can delete the comments after you have edited the contents into your question. That makes the comments easier to follow.

Comment: done. Thank you for this info

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function strpos that find dot in string `stripos()`. To next you must send position to `substr()` where first param string, second param is start(in your case 0) and last funded position strpos.

```
$result = substr($string, 0, stripos($string, "."));
```

Comment: Sorry but how my code must look like. I'm new :) Where I need to add your code?

Comment: You could get need string with use sql query(select), then process string with use php code and in last use sql update then send to database

Comment: Could you please help me how my code have to look like? Thank you